# Emplacement de « n'est pas »

Tags: grammaire

J'apprends le code de la route depuis peu et j'ai lu une phrase qui me me trouble. Il s'agit de l'emplacement de « n'est pas ».

> **L'usage de l'avertisseur sonore, s'il est interdit en agglomération, n'est pas, contrairement à ce qu'on pense, interdit en montagne.**

Pourquoi n'est-ce pas :

> Contrairement à ce qu'on pense, ce n'est pas interdit en montagne.

?

Pourriez-vous me donner quelques autres exemples pour que je puisse comprendre plus clairement ?

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit simplement d'une tournure de phrase différente, mais les deux tournures sont correctes.

Comme on peut le voir, la phrase fonctionne très bien sans la partie "*contrairement à ce que l'on pense*" (je vais imaginer que la phrase ne contient pas "*s'il est interdit en agglomération*", car le principe est le même) :

> L'usage de l'avertisseur sonore est interdit en montagne.

Il s'agit ici de la **proposition principale**.

La proposition "*contrairement à ce que l'on pense*" est une [**proposition subordonnée circonstancielle**](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/propositions-subordonnees.php) ([de comparaison](https://www.maxicours.com/se/cours/les-subordonnees-circonstancielles-de-comparaison-les-comparatives/)). Il s'agit d'un complément de phrase qui peut être déplacé ou supprimé. Sa seule utilité est d'apporter une information supplémentaire pour aider à la compréhension.

Plus d'informations sur les propositions circonstancielles (notamment tous les différents types et les règles associées) sont disponibles [ici](https://www.lelivrescolaire.fr/manuel/1335887/cyclades/chapitre/1336624/grammaire/page/1353802/20-les-propositions-subordonnees-circonstancielles/lecon).

Un autre exemple :

> Quand j'aurai fini, je viendrai te voir.

peut aussi s'écrire

> Je viendrai te voir quand j'aurai fini.

Dans cette phrase, "*Quand j'aurai fini*" est également une proposition subordonnée circonstancielle (de temps, cette fois-ci).